# angular js routing not working without any js errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on routing application.here I have code for index and controller js please show me where I  am going wrong.

**my angular-js code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="helloApp">
<head>
  <title>HelloWorld</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Hello World Sample Program</h1>
  </div>
    <p><a href="#/page">Go to page</a></p>
    <p><a href="#/page1">Go to page1</a></p>
    <p><a href="#/page2">Go to page2</a></p>
    <p><a href="#/page3">Go to page3</a></p>


  <div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Type Your Name</label>
          <div class="col-md-4">
               <input type="text" ng-model="name"  class="form-control"/>
               <span>Hello {{ name }}</span>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**my js code**

```
'use strict';

    var helloApp = angular.module( "helloApp", ['ui.bootstrap','ngRoute'] ).
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller: 'HelloCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/page.html'
    })
    .when('/page', {
      controller: 'HelloCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/page.html'
    })
    .when('/page1', {
      controller: 'HelloCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/page1.html'
    })
    .when('/page2', {
      controller: 'HelloCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/page2.html'
    })
    .when('/page3', {
      controller: 'HelloCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/page3.html'
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/page'
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add   `<div ng-view></div>` into your html file

[ng-view](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

Comment: i have added below to href  , but may i know why ng-view needed ?? i am just started to learn.

Comment: ng-view is a container that show the html page while you routing to the pages. Without ng-view you cannot do angular route. 

You can use ui-router instead of angular-router. Which have more feature than angular-router , like nested views, multiple views ..

Comment: i  got this error now in console Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=HelloCtrl&p1=not%20a            1.#QNAN0unction%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: You have to add controller 'HelloCtrl' in your app

Comment: helloApp .controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope) {

});
add this

Answer (score 0):

Where is your

`<div ng-view></div>` to show the routed location.

Answer (score 0):

try this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="helloApp">
<head>
  <title>HelloWorld</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Hello World Sample Program</h1>
  </div>
    <p><a href="#/page">Go to page</a></p>
    <p><a href="#/page1">Go to page1</a></p>
    <p><a href="#/page2">Go to page2</a></p>
    <p><a href="#/page3">Go to page3</a></p>


  <div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Type Your Name</label>
          <div class="col-md-4">
               <input type="text" ng-model="name"  class="form-control"/>
               <span>Hello {{ name }}</span>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="col-md-2" ng-view></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```